# Making list from textarea value by new lines

Tags: javascript, jquery

This may be very easy to solve but my brain is dead for some reason I can't find out the right road to success :(

I have some text area where by pressing enter for each word or more words in one line I get an list item.

```
$(document).on('click','#addList', function(){
            var lines = $('#list').val().split(/\n/);
            var texts = []
            for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
              if (/\S/.test(lines[i])) {
                texts.push($.trim(lines[i]));
              }
            }
            var list = JSON.stringify(texts);
            for(var e=0; e<list.length; e++){
                var li = li+'<li class="c1_2v">'+list[e]+'</li>'; 
            }
            $('.content').append($('<ul>'+li+'</ul>'));
});
```

By doing this $.trim I am getting problem if I have more words in one line but it is useful if I have more empty new lines or spaces before first word.

Example:

```
<textarea>
    this    is 

a

something
that
I want to add to new lists
</textarea>
```

By my code and first  for loop I get something like: `['this','is','a','something','that','I','want','to','add','to','new','lists']`

By second for loop I get into `li tags every letter or character from [ to ]` inside `li` tags

I don't understand regex I saw many websites but it is not getting into my head so even if you add it as more easier answer without explanation what is used for what I wouldn't know how it works..

And this is basically what I need to get in .content div:

```
<ul>
  <li class="c1_2v">this is</li>
  <li class="c1_2v">a</li>
  <li class="c1_2v">something</li>
  <li class="c1_2v">that</li>
  <li class="c1_2v">I want to add to new lists</li>
</ul>
```

I will add snippet how it works till now:

```js
 $(document).on('click','#addList', function(){
          var lines = $('#list').val().split(/\n/);
          var texts = []
          for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            if (/\S/.test(lines[i])) {
              texts.push($.trim(lines[i]));
            }
          }
          var list = JSON.stringify(texts);
          for(var e=0; e<list.length; e++){
           var li = li+'<li class="c1_2v">'+list[e]+'</li>'; 
          }
          $('.content').append($('<ul>'+li+'</ul>'));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="list"></textarea>
<button id="addList">Add</button>
<div class="content"></div>
```

And also there is something undefined Idk what :(

As @AlexKudryashev commented I used array as string not as array and if I add var li before for loop undefined will go away.

Comment: The issue is in `var list = JSON.stringify(texts);`. Your `list` is a string. Remove it and use `texts` array instead.

Comment: Oh yea as I said probably very simple thing.... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified solution that requires no regex. You can use array.filter and array.map to consolidate.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {
  var text = document.querySelector('textarea').value;
  var lines = text.split('\n');
  var html = lines
    .filter(line => line.trim() !== '')
    .map(line => `<li class="c1_2v">${line}</li>`)
    .join('');
  document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<textarea>
    this    is 

a

something
that
I want to add to new lists
</textarea>

<button>Click me</button>

<ul><!--output goes here--></ul>
```

Comment: Nice solution but I used mine as removing JSON.stringify. But anyway I accepted your answer because it is nice solution.

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).on('click', '#addList', function() {
  var lines = $('#list').val().split(/\n/);
  var texts = []
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (/\S/.test(lines[i])) {
      texts.push($.trim(lines[i]));
    }
  }
  //var list = JSON.stringify(texts);
  var list = texts;
  var li = "";

  for (var e = 0; e < list.length; e++) {
    li = li + '<li class="c1_2v">' + list[e] + '</li>';
  }

  $('.content').append($('<ul>' + li + '</ul>'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="list"></textarea>
<button id="addList">Add</button>
<div class="content"></div>
```

`JSON.stringify` converts the value to JSON string. So you are looping every string instead of the array. Also, you were getting `undefined` since `li` is not defined. To avoid simply define `li` as `""` empty string.